# Python face detection error with opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, face-detection

I try to use python face detection software. But when I launch it i recive this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file /build/opencv-FWWjHr/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 4991
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "riconoscimentofacciale.py", line 57, in <module>
    faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
cv2.error: The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)
```

the source code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cv
import cv2
import time
import Image

def DetectFace(image, faceCascade):

    min_size = (20,20)
    image_scale = 2
    haar_scale = 1.1
    min_neighbors = 3
    haar_flags = 0

    # Allocate the temporary images
    grayscale = cv.CreateImage((image.width, image.height), 8, 1)
    smallImage = cv.CreateImage(
            (
                cv.Round(image.width / image_scale),
                cv.Round(image.height / image_scale)
            ), 8 ,1)

    # Convert color input image to grayscale
    cv.CvtColor(image, grayscale, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

    # Scale input image for faster processing
    cv.Resize(grayscale, smallImage, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR)

    # Equalize the histogram
    cv.EqualizeHist(smallImage, smallImage)

    # Detect the faces
    faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(
            smallImage, faceCascade, cv.CreateMemStorage(0),
            haar_scale, min_neighbors, haar_flags, min_size
        )

    # If faces are found
    if faces:
        for ((x, y, w, h), n) in faces:
            # the input to cv.HaarDetectObjects was resized, so scale the
            # bounding box of each face and convert it to two CvPoints
            pt1 = (int(x * image_scale), int(y * image_scale))
            pt2 = (int((x + w) * image_scale), int((y + h) * image_scale))
            cv.Rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, cv.RGB(255, 0, 0), 5, 8, 0)

    return image

#----------
# M A I N
#----------

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
#capture = cv.CaptureFromFile("test.avi")

faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
#faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")
#faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
#faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml")

while (cv.WaitKey(15)==-1):
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    image = DetectFace(img, faceCascade)
    cv.ShowImage("face detection test", image)

cv.ReleaseCapture(capture)
```

I have set-up all right, I followed [guide](http://www.lucaamore.com/?p=638)

I download all, install all, create and put the right file/drectory. But still face the error.

Comment: please use the cv2 api, not the deprecated cv one (which is gone in opencv3) also [see sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/facedetect.py)

Comment: For Face Detection i.e. If its Obama's face or Trumps in real time check out the source code of this GitHub Repo https://github.com/UBISOFT-1/Project_Exodus.git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most common error new developer faces here is old code which refers to old xml file.

Download this [haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/albertz/screenshooting/master/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml) xml file and replace

```
faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
```

with

```
faceCascade = cv.Load("Complete_path_of_THiS_NEW_File")
```

if you downlaoded the file in downloadfolder then

```
faceCascade = cv.Load("/home/webadmin/Downloads/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem! I followed your step and now is all working